# Arch Linux with Nvidia Lagging very badly

Tags: linux, graphics-card, arch-linux, nvidia

I recently built a pc with Ryzen 9 5900x and a RTX 3060Ti.

Everything on windows works fine, but linux installation lags very badly.

The only installation that is working well for me is Mate with i3.

Things get bad especially when I start some chromium based apps like Chrome, Spotify, Slack, Discord, Hyper terminal and so on.

I have tried switching between nouveau and nvidia drivers. But I am getting the same result in both cases.

Some help in debugging would be helpful.

PC Config:

`````
                  .o+`                   --------------------------------- 
                 `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Kernel: 5.16.16-arch1-1 
               `+oooooo:                 Uptime: 1 min 
               -+oooooo+:                Packages: 1248 (pacman) 
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Resolution: 3840x2160 
           `/++++++++++++++:             DE: MATE 1.26.0 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           WM: i3 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          Theme: BlackMATE [GTK2/3] 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Icons: mate [GTK2/3] 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Terminal: mate-terminal 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Terminal Font: DankMono Nerd Font Italic 10 
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X (24) @ 4.000GHz 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti Lite Hash Rate 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    Memory: 1139MiB / 64277MiB 
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `/
`````

Comment: since `i3` works fine for you, did you try switching to XORG on your other DEs/WMs?

Comment: I did but with no success. But even with i3, chrome and chromium-based apps are very unreliable.

Comment: and just to make sure, Wayland's lagging as well, yes? Also, did you try downgrading a version as mentioned in the [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Bad_performance_after_installing_a_new_driver_version)?